# Unable to Build GraalVM Image for Spring Boot 3

Tags: java, spring, graalvm

I am getting this error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.graalvm.buildtools:native-maven-plugin:0.9.27:compile (default-cli) on project legacy-server: Execution default-cli of goal org.graalvm.buildtools:native-maven-plugin:0.9.27:compile failed: GraalVM native-image is missing on your system. 
[ERROR] Make sure that GRAALVM_HOME environment variable is present.
```

However I already have this in my env:

```
(base) smitshah@Smits-MBP legacy-service % echo $JAVA_HOME
/Users/smitshah/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/graalvm-jdk-17.0.9+11.1/Contents/Home
```

And

```
(base) smitshah@Smits-MBP legacy-service % echo $GRAALVM_HOME 
/Users/smitshah/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/graalvm-jdk-17.0.9+11.1/Contents/Home
```

Background:
I am trying to upgrade my App From Spring Boot 2.4.X to 3.1

Since the expectation is I need to build an Docker image out of this, I thought it will be good time to upgrade my repo to use GraalVM. Since they have made it harder to have Docker image for Java 17.

Here is the PR: https://github.com/quiz-roulette/legacy-service/pull/1 with all the changes I did to produce this error.

The command I ran:

```
mvn clean -Pnative native:compile
```

Comment: Have you installed the `native-image` plugin ? You can test whether it is installed by running `native-image --version`. If the shell reports some `Command not found`, then please run `gu install native-image` to install the `native-image` plugin.

Comment: Spot On, but I have already ran the install that gave me output: `Downloading: Artifacts catalog from gds.oracle.com
Skipping ULN EE channels, no username provided.
Downloading: Component catalog from www.graalvm.org
Processing Component: Native Image
Component Native Image (org.graalvm.native-image) is already installed.` But when i run `native-image --version` says `command not found`

Comment: I am able to start the native build locally, i.e. the maven-setup seems correct. If I interpret everything correctly, then you are on MacOS? Can you double-check the [official installation guide (`graalvm.org`)](https://www.graalvm.org/latest/docs/getting-started/macos) to verify that GraalVM is installed correctly?

Comment: @Turing85 You are right, something went wrong with my ~./zshrc file.. It seems I used the above documentation that moved the graalvm to /Library folder but i configured /Users/smit/Library folder. Hence the conflict caused it act weridly. Addtionally there were 2 11.0.9 versions in the /Library .. I removed one. Now It seem to proceeed.

Answer (score 1):

2 Mistakes:

1. Following this documentation, https://www.graalvm.org/latest/docs/getting-started/macos/, it moves the graalvm to `/Library` folder not to `/Users/<username>/Library`, Because I configured `/Users/<username>/Library` in my `~/.zhrc` file, It caused the issue.
2. Also, `/Library` had 2 `11.0.9` folders of java versions. So I removed one and kept the graalvm one.